# Presentation API / Redirecting actions on multiple views

Tags: java, android, view, actionlistener

I am working on a (previously created project) and don't want to throw away most of their code.Thus, I want to do something like "replicating actions on a view (like setText, animating, ...) onto a different object, but the same view":

Something like (how I would love if it would work like this):

```
someView.addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener()
    {
        public void onViewChangedAction(ViewChangedAction action)
            {
                myotherviewobject.executeAction(action)
            }
    });
```

This would be the simplest way, but I haven't found an API to do so. There are actually multiple custom views etc. So I need a very "general" solution. Does a solution like this exist?

If not... any ideas on how to do this in a usable way without interfering too much into other's people's code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your vision is that you want a piece of what's on the touchscreen to be mirrored to the `Presentation`, my [CWAC-Presentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation) library has [classes dedicated for that scenario](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation#usage-mirroring-presentation-classes).

Comment: Hey. This is great!
However, The "mirroring" to a presentation is only the first usecase. Its actually the first step into chromecasting, where I'd love to have a similiar approach. (like with the onViewChangedAction creating some kind of message which the html5/js on the cc supports). However, I dont think this is really doable in a "convenient" way. So I'll throw it "off board" for the moment. 
Your approach is much simpler for the moment (I didnt know that I could actually "just" reuse the fragment's inflated view.). Please make an answer and I'll accept it as soon as I get it working!

Comment: + as its using the same view objects... will it also inherit the same changes etc? (or even display the same video ?) Yes, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your vision is that you want a piece of what's on the touchscreen to be mirrored to the Presentation, my [CWAC-Presentation library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation) has [classes dedicated for that scenario](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation#usage-mirroring-presentation-classes). In particular, `MirrorPresentationFragment` and a source like `MirrorWebViewFragment` give you code like shown in the sample app:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
  not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
  a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
 */

package com.commonsware.cwac.preso.demo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import com.commonsware.cwac.preso.MirrorPresentationFragment;
import com.commonsware.cwac.preso.MirroringWebViewFragment;
import com.commonsware.cwac.preso.PresentationFragment;
import com.commonsware.cwac.preso.PresentationHelper;

public class MirrorPresentationActivity extends Activity implements
    PresentationHelper.Listener {
  PresentationFragment preso=null;
  PresentationHelper helper=null;
  MirroringWebViewFragment source=null;

  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mirror_presentation);

    helper=new PresentationHelper(this, this);
    source=
        (MirroringWebViewFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.source);
    source.getWebView().getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    source.getWebView().loadUrl("http://commonsware.com");
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    helper.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    helper.onPause();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void clearPreso(boolean switchToInline) {
    if (preso != null) {
      preso.dismiss();
      preso=null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void showPreso(Display display) {
    preso=buildPreso(display);
    preso.show(getFragmentManager(), "preso");
  }

  private PresentationFragment buildPreso(Display display) {
    MirrorPresentationFragment result=
        MirrorPresentationFragment.newInstance(this, display);

    source.setMirror(result);

    return(result);
  }
}
```

The net effect is whatever the user does in the `WebView` in the activity will be mirrored into the `Presentation`.

> as its using the same view objects... will it also inherit the same changes etc? (or even display the same video ?)

The mirroring classes basically involve drawing the contents of the mirror source to a `Bitmap` in addition to drawing it to the screen. Anything that uses `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` under the covers won't work, but other stuff should generally work OK. Hence, video won't work via mirroring. For that, I'd try to just show it on the `Presentation`, with the phone/tablet as a controller.